# Which hook should be used to validate custom form fields on the login form?

Tags: plugins, hooks, login

I've added a custom input field with `login_form` hook.

So, I need to process the post data to validate.
I've used the `lostpassword_post` for `lostpassword_form` and works great, but I cant find a hook to validate my data at login form.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the action `'login_init'` to catch all calls to `wp-login.php`.

Sample code:

```
add_action( 'login_init', 'wpse_51227_validate_custom_field' );

function wpse_51227_validate_custom_field()
{
    if ( ! isset ( $_POST['special_custom'] )
        return;

    if ( ! is_numeric( $_POST['special_custom'] )
        // handle the error
}
```

There are two important global variables available:

- `$errors` is an instance of `WP_Error`. Maybe you want to use it to store error data.
- `$action` is the current action. Maybe you want to rest it to `login` to prevent a redirect if the user input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really tested this but I'm just guessing by how I do it with the *registration & profile pages*.

Try something like this:

```
function my_login_errors( $errors ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['custom_field'] ) )
        $errors->add( 'empty_custom_field', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter some info.' );
    return $errors;
}
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'my_login_errors' );
```

**Note:** Modify the `custom_field` part and the **message** accordingly.